# Java How to Write a Common Util to Print the Currently Executed Function Name For All Functions?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I want to print the function names for quite a few functions that I run. Here is my current code which I found very repetitive in every single function. Is there a way (such as annotations) to make the code more concise and reusable?

I want to create such a common utility for all classes, instead of a single class.

```
class SomeClass {
    void func1() {
        String methodName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
        System.out.println(methodName);
        // execute func1
    }
    void func2() {
        String methodName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
        System.out.println(methodName);
        // execute func2
    }
    void func3() {
        String methodName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
        System.out.println(methodName);
        // execute func3
    }
}
```

I have tried to create another class to wrap the repetitive lines as below.

```
class FuncInfo {
    public void printFuncName() {
        String methodName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
        System.out.println(methodName);
    }
}
```

```
class SomeClass {
    FuncInfo funcInfo = new FuncInfo();
    void func1() {
        funcInfo.printFuncName;
        // execute func1
    }
   // ...
}
```

However, it prints the common util class and function names ("printFuncName"), instead of the method names that I need ("func1", "func2" or "func3").

Comment: The easiest change here is to create a method that returns `new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()`. You can also use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()` to get the name of the calling method.

Comment: You could instead have a function that prints the name of the method who calls it. You can wrap it somehow "fancy" using advanced techniques, or just calling it every time you want the name of the method that's being executed

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate this task to a commonly used function:

```
class SomeClass() {
    void fun() {
        String methodName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
        System.out.println(methodName);
        // execute func1
    }
    void func1() {
        fun();
        // execute func1
    }
    void func2() {
        fun();
        // execute func2
    }
    void func3() {
        fun();
        // execute func3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What if I want to make it a common utility for all classes instead of only 1 class?

Comment: @DEmma your idea is a good one. You can do that, furthermore, you should do that if you want to do this in multiple classes.  If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it. A simple idea is to declare that method public static. Public so you can reach it from other classes and static so you will not have to instantiate it.